# MSDTC between Windows 7 (32bit) and Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, com+, msdtc

I am currently attempting to create a test environment for a website which is using a mixture of classic ASP and ASP.NET. (The original machines are running old versions of Windows Server, so the configuration is not to easy to mimic)

Unfortunately, I am having problems interacting from Windows 7 to the Server 2003.
The error I am getting from my test application (which simply fires a stored procedure) is as follows:
New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator.
After reading various articles online, I believe I have set-up the COM+ side of things on the Windows 7 machine correctly. If I change my connection string to target the old server, it succeeds.

I then ran MSDTC Simulation V1.9 and the error I recieved was as follows:

```
DTCping log file: C:\Users\whelans\Desktop\dtping\[servername].log
RPC server is ready
Please Start Partner DTCping before pinging
++++++++++++Validating Remote Computer Name++++++++++++
Please refer to following log file for details:
    C:\Users\whelans\Desktop\dtping\[servername].log
Invoking RPC method on [servername]
Problem:fail to invoke remote RPC method
Error(0x6D9) at dtcping.cpp @303
-->RPC pinging exception
-->1753(There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.)
RPC test failed
```

I then tried changing my connection string password and it fails due to invalid login, so I believe the COM is reaching the server's database. The user also has full permissions on the database.

I notice in the COM+ Window, that the component in use is spinning as if communicating with the server, however, it seems the server is rejection the connection.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I have now also ran DTCTester, as i read that DTCPing will always fail on Windows 7, here was the result:

```
C:\Users\whelans\Desktop\dtping>dtctester.exe TestDatabase username password
Executed: dtctester.exe
DSN:  TestDatabase
User Name: username
Password: password
tablename= #dtc9033
Creating Temp Table for Testing: #dtc9033
Warning: No Columns in Result Set From Executing: 'create table #dtc9033 (ival i
nt)'
Initializing DTC
Beginning DTC Transaction
Enlisting Connection in Transaction
Executing SQL Statement in DTC Transaction
Inserting into Temp...insert into #dtc9033 values (1)
Warning: No Columns in Result Set From Executing: 'insert into #dtc9033 values (
1) '
Verifying Insert into Temp...select * from #dtc9033 (should be 1): 1
Press enter to commit transaction.

Commiting DTC Transaction
Releasing DTC Interface Pointers
Successfully Released pTransaction Pointer.
Disconnecting from Database and Cleaning up Handles
```

Comment: Can you post that as an answer, and mark it as accepted?